# Switching from World Space to Local has no effect on rotation tool

Tags: bones

When I press R (followed by X, Y or Z), I can rotate the selected bone.

No matter which setting (Local, World, Gimbal, etc.) I select in Blender, the rotation method doesn't change for me.

Also, changing the Transform Pivot Point doesn't change the way the rotation tool works for me.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it doesn't have an effect if one uses the shortcut R.

However, when one presses the rotation tool, it actually changes and displays it as well:

[image]

[image]